# relation between two pairs of orthogonal latin squares

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are orthogonal latin squares of order $n$ and $B_1$ and $B_2$ are orthogonal latin squares of order $m$ then the latin squares $A_1 \times B_1$ and $A_2 \times B_2$ are orthogonal.

It seems that this statement is related to quasi-groups but I don't know how...

multiplication of latin squares are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Definition)  in the "tensor product of linear maps" section.

Comment: How do you multiply two latin squares?

Comment: @TonyK i added a link up there

Comment: But a latin square is not a linear map.

Comment: By the way, once we have sorted this out, I expect that you will want $A_1 \times B_1$ and $A_2 \times B_2$, not $A_1 \times A_2$ and $B_1 \times B_2$.

Comment: @TonyK nope it's not a linear map but the multiplication is like that , look at this photo https://pictub.club/image/scllSW

Comment: @TonyK it's 6.6.2 proposition in  Peter J. Cameron's Combinatorics: Topics, Techniques, Algorithms